# setTextColor() and setTextSize() not working for dynamically created radio buttons in Android

Tags: android

I've created `RadioGroup` buttons `Dynamically` and `Static` as well. Everything works fine for the static `RadioButtons`, but the `setTextColor()` and `setTextSize()` doesn't work for the dynamically created `RadioButtons`. I've Included my code below with snapshots...
`layout_activity.xml`

```
        <!-- Here Dynamic -->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutTopicGrade"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#BCC6CC"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <RadioGroup 
                    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:paddingRight="5dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <!-- Here Static -->
        <HorizontalScrollView    
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.75" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutGames"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E5E4E2"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioGroup 
                    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="33dip"
                    android:minWidth="40dip"
                    android:text="RadioButton1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:textAppearance="@dimen/text_size"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_color"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:checked="true" />   

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:minHeight="33dip"
                    android:minWidth="40dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@dimen/text_size"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_color"
                    android:text="RadioButton2" />    

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:minHeight="33dip"
                    android:minWidth="40dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@dimen/text_size"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_color"
                    android:text="RadioButton3" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I've created `values-ldpi`, `values-mdpi`, `values-hdpi` folders and so on. Inside these folder I've created `dimen.xml` with text size values `14dip`, `16dip`,`18dip`and so on as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_size">20dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

`radio_text_color.xml` as:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_checked="true" 
        android:color="#FFF" />

    <item  android:color="#000" />
</selector>
```

`buttonbackground.xml` as:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/segment_white"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/segment_grey_press"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/segment_grey_press"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/segment_white" />
</selector>
```

`mainActivity.java` as:

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity {

    RadioButton rb;
    RadioGroup rg;


    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "InlinedApi", "ResourceAsColor" })
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_board);

        rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

        RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
            rb = new RadioButton(this);
            rb.setId(i);
            rb.setTag("Tag"+i);
            rb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            //convert pixels to dip
            int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 33, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            rb.setMinHeight(height);
            rb.setMinWidth(width);
            rb.setText("Button"+i);
            rb.setChecked(true);
            rb.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());
            rb.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
            rb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.drawable.radio_text_color));
            rb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourbuttonbackground);
            params.topMargin = 5;
            rb.setLayoutParams(params);
            rg.addView(rb);
            rb.setOnClickListener(buttonClicked);
        }
    }

    public OnClickListener buttonClicked = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int _id =  v.getId();
            String str = v.getTag().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"str: "+str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game_board, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

`Output Screenshot`
[image]
As you can see on the right side(Static buttons) of the screenshot, second button is selected and the Text color of the selected button is `White` where as remaining two is `Black`, On the left side(Dynamic buttons) the text color doesn't change, by default it is black. Even the height of the buttons are different, but I'm applying same properties in both place.
`How to get same output either it is Dynamic or Static?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting color state list instead for ex:

```
ColorStateList myColorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, //1
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, //2
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_pressed} //3
            },
            new int[] {
                Color.RED, //1
                Color.GREEN, //2
                Color.BLUE //3
            }
        );
    rb.setTextColor(myColorStateList);
```

or  simply call

```
rb.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.radio_text_color));
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Vipul Mittal, Its works now.... Did you noticed the height of the buttons... in both case I've given `wrap_content`, but why it differs in final output?